# How to smooth transition from Large Header to small static header (Javascript/CSS)

Tags: javascript, css

I have a large centered masthead (our logo and the page/section that the user is on) that I have on my pages and when the user scrolls past what would be the masthead a mini masthead/header appears (a smaller version of the logo and the page the user is on, that is all left aligned). What I am trying to figure out is how to make the transition from the larger masthead to the smaller one look better than the quick jump-cut that currently happens.

Here is my current code:

```js
/*********************************
 *
 * File: resources/js/system.header_bar.js
 *   
 * JavaScript for Header Bar on page.
 *
 * Version 1.0.1
 *
 * Date Created: 20190702.0712
 * Date Modified:20190702.1416 
 * 
 ************************************/

//JavaScript to control Header Scroll. 
window.onscroll = function() {
  'use strict';
  OTE_HeaderFunction();
};

var header = document.getElementById("header-myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop - 50;
var logo_sm = document.getElementById("header-Logo_sm");
var pg_name = document.getElementById("header-Logo_PageName_sm");

function OTE_HeaderFunction() {
  'use strict';
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    logo_sm.style.display = "inline";
    pg_name.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    logo_sm.style.display = "none";
    pg_name.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/*********************************
  *
  * File: resources/css/system.bar01_header.css
  *   
  * {{APP DESCR}}
  * CSS for Header Bar on page.
  *
  * Version BAR01_1.0
  *
  * Date Created: 20190702.0712
  * Date Modified: 
  * 
  ************************************/

.header-top-container {
  background: rgb(242, 246, 248);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(242, 246, 248, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 230, 235, 1) 51%, rgba(224, 239, 249, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(242, 246, 248, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 230, 235, 1) 51%, rgba(224, 239, 249, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(242, 246, 248, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 230, 235, 1) 51%, rgba(224, 239, 249, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#f2f6f8", endColorstr="#e0eff9", GradientType=1);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #05336b;
}

.header-top-container h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  /*#05336b;*/
  line-height: .5;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .header-top-container h1 {
    font-size: calc(14px + (32 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1000 - 300)));
  }
}


/* WITHOUT THE BLOCK BELOW, THE FONT WOULD CONTINUE TO GROW */

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .header-top-container h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}

.header-main-logo {
  width: calc(275px + (590 - 275) * ((100vw - 300px)/(1600 - 300)));
  height: auto;
  max-width: 590px;
  margin: auto;
}

.header-bar {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: rgb(242, 246, 248);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(242, 246, 248, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 230, 235, 1) 51%, rgba(224, 239, 249, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(242, 246, 248, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 230, 235, 1) 51%, rgba(224, 239, 249, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(242, 246, 248, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 230, 235, 1) 51%, rgba(224, 239, 249, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#f2f6f8", endColorstr="#e0eff9", GradientType=1);
  color: #05336b;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  border: 0 0 4 4 ridge #05336b;
}

.header-bar h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #05336b;
  line-height: .5;
  display: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
  /*background: #05336b;*/
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 9px 22px 0px rgba(159, 168, 218, .75);
  ;
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 9px 22px 0px rgba(159, 168, 218, .75);
  ;
  box-shadow: 7px 9px 22px 0px rgba(159, 168, 218, .75);
  ;
  display: inline;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- other formatting and style sheets here -->
  <!-- Page Header -->
  <title>User Menu</title>

  <style>
    .header-main-logo {
      width: calc(275px + (590 - 275) * ((100vw - 300px)/(1600 - 300)));
      height: auto;
      max-width: 590px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .menu-bar-item {
      font-size: calc(12px + (24 - 12) * ((100vw - 300px)/(1600 - 300)));
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header-top-container">

    <div class="w3-mobile w3-content">
      <h1>
        <img src="./resources/logo/bc_ote_scfe_PMS288.png" alt="Logo" class="header-main-logo" />
        <br>
        <span id="header-Logo_PageName_lg">5t3User Menu </span>

      </h1>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="header-bar" id="header-myHeader">
    <img src="./resources/logo/bc_ote_scfe_PMS288.png" alt="Logo (Smaller)" style="width:30%;height:auto;max-width:350px;display: none;" id="header-Logo_sm" /><br />
    <h3 id="header-Logo_PageName_sm">User Menu</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="w3-row-padding w3-mobile">
      <div class="w3-content">
        <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="./resources/js/system.header_bar.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

What I am trying to do is get the logo so smoothly transition from when it is in the header-top-container to the header-bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) which will make it happen more smoothly and gives it a nice-looking animation effect.